# Should we make Alecos post more riddles or trick questions? =D

Tags: discussion

Well, after [this question by Alecos](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/18811/monopolies-are-just-a-mathematical-misunderstanding?), I was left wondering if it wouldn't be nice to promote this type of questions? Maybe in a blog associated with this community.

What do you think?

Comment: forget a blog, the man should write a textbook.

Comment: I completely agree @EconJohn ;)

Comment: @EconJohn agreed with one minor quible. Where would he find the time to answer all our questions then?

Answer (score 2):

I fully support posting puzzles. But the referred question is hardly one. It has a deliberate mistake embedded in misleading wording. What is the point of that? The number of "find where I have confused you" type of question is boundless. I do not think we should flood the site with them. Ultimately (as I see it) this is a Q&A site, and not a place to entertain ourselves with games and tricks. Adding fairly spurious questions will just make it harder for other people to find the questions they are looking for.

Comment: I see your point, lucho. That's why I suggested those type of questions in a blog. That way, both could be independent.

Comment: "The purpose of studying economics is not to acquire a set of ready-made answers to economic questions, but **to learn how to avoid being deceived by economists**." - Joan Robinson

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not a fan of puzzles created for amusement, trick questions, misleading wording, or deliberate mistakes.

This site is here to help people with real problems they face. By having such questions answered, then anyone who comes along afterwards with the same problem, will find a solution.

Amusing puzzles, trick questions, misleading wording and deliberate mistakes are all a diversion from that.

Can I suggest that the chat room is a great place for such trickery and recreation?